# How do I turn a collection'1/system.object into something Invoke-WebRequest will accept?

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, collections, type-conversion

In my powershell script I need to convert a variable into something Invoke-WebRequest accepts. Example :

```
     $Server_Names.GetType();

     IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType            
     -------- -------- ----                                     --------            
     True     True     Collection`1                           System.Object
```

How would I turn this variable `$Server_Names` into something that Invoke-WebRequest accepts?Would I need to covert this variable into an array first?

Essentially the `$Server_Names` variable is just this:

```
server01.administration.us 
server02.administration.us
server03.administration.us
```

This is what I get when I run `$Server_Names | % { $_.GetType() }`

```
 IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType            
 -------- -------- ----                                     --------            
 True     True     String                                   System.Object       
 True     True     String                                   System.Object       
 True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Comment: which parameter of Invoke-WebRequest shall accept your variable? I presume it's Uri, which is scalar, so doesn't support arrays/lists. You need foreach loop or pipeline foreach-object.

Comment: @Max Well, I think if it was an array, I could make it work with this: `$Server_Names | % { Invoke-WebRequest $_ }`. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Collection .Net type supports IEnumerable, so your construction shall work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2.

Comment: Can you provide more information, what are you trying to accomplish? Why are you using Invoke-webrequest?

Comment: @michaeldejulia   I am trying to send a HTTP request to a group of servers recently launched to see if they are online. The script accepts input for how many servers will be tested. If the user inputs 2, the script will send HTTP request to `server01.administration.us` and to `server02.administration.us`. However, `Invoke-WebRequest` won't accept what I currently have.

Comment: @Max Could you give me an example of how this would work? I read through all the documentation you provided but I'm still a bit confused

Comment: Sure, but could you do additional testing before, please? Can you run `$Server_Names | % { $_.GetType() }`? To ensure this is a string or URI. And possible provide a code which produces the content of `$Server_Names` variable.

Comment: @Max I added the `$Server_Names | % { $_.GetType() }` output in my latest edit

Comment: Both arrays and collections (and any other .Net classes with enumeration support) are suitable for foreach loop and % / foreach-object commandlet. Since inner collection type is string, then you shall be able to run the code, you proposed in the second comment. have you tried? `$Server_Names | ForEach-Object { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ }` worked just fine for me.

Comment: @Max Thanks, that one worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try that:

```
$Server_Names | ForEach-Object { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ }
```